# French character in SQL where

Tags: php, sql-server, character-encoding

I'm running SQL Server for db and using PHP for development. When I run the query to select users from city `Pointe-à-Pitre` on SQL Server, it fetches the result. However when I run the same query using PHP, it fetches an empty set.

The query is like this

```
SELECT * FROM [my_database].[dbo].[users] WHERE city='Pointe-à-Pitre'
```

Comment: `...WHERE city=N'Pointe-à-Pitre'`

Comment: try to change the charset to utf of the table like below and try

alter table tablename convert to character set utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: @sandeep_kosta i forgot to mention that i don't have any write access to db.

Comment: then you should contact your db administrator b'coz i think this is the only way to make it work

Comment: How do you connect to SQL Server the old MSSQL-driver or the current SQLSRV? If the latter see MSDN: [How to: Send and Retrieve UTF-8 Data Using Built-In UTF-8 Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc626307(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: @AbdulBasit, What is the data type of city column in user table?

Comment: @dbrumann thanks :) it works.

Comment: @MUHAMMADTASADDUQALI  I am using nvarchar. It works now. Thanks to dbrumann

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was connecting to the server. I followed [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc626307(v=sql.105).aspx) (thanks [@dbrumann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1166880/dbrumann)) and modified the connection by setting `"CharacterSet"` to `"UTF-8"`.